# taking input from a file_2

Tags: c++, filestream, file-io

i am taking input from a file row-wise...each row contains three or less columns...
everything is fine if the line in the file is like

```
     lda #5
```

or

```
label +lda #5
```

but if a line starts with '+' like

```
+lda #5
```

that line is not being input....why is this so?

the input taking code is

```
ifstream in(asmfile,ios::in);
char c;
string str[3];
string subset;
long locctr=0;
int i=0;


while((c=in.get())!=EOF)
{
    in.putback(c);
    str[0]="";
    str[1]="";
    str[2]="";
    i=0;

    while((c=in.get())!='\n' && c!=EOF)
    {

        in.putback(c);
        in>>str[i++];

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `EOF`. If you do use `EOF`, don't use `char`, but `int`.

Comment: Your code performs an invalid access if there are more than three characters on one line, too.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure where you were trying to go with your code, but it seems very poorly constructed to me, and you tagged the question as C++, so I would recommend you use the standard C++ idiom to read a file line by line:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

std::ifstream infile(asmfile);
std::string line;

while (std::getline(infile, line))
{
  // process "line"
  // e.g. "lines.push_back(line);" , with "std::vector<std::string> lines;"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As written, I believe the posted code will read the lines shown as examples.  In fact, I just now ran it, and it also read the line that you indicated would not work (and it reads just two "words" since the `>>` operator in that case will use white space as a delimiter for the string.

A possible reason for the failure is if the line preceding the `+lda #5` line has more than three words (delimited by spaces).  That would result in undefined behavior (quite possibly an access violation) since the `str` array has only three elements, and there is no check for the case where more than three words are on the line.